# Parse a date string in a specific locale (not timezone!)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

With MomentJS, if necessary I can set a locale on a specific moment instance (rather than globally) using `.locale` (or `.lang` in older versions). How can I parse a string using a specific locale other than the global one? Since the `moment` function itself is what we use for parsing, and there doesn't seem to be a `.set` variant that does full parsing?

E.g.:

```js
// Assume the default locale is 'en' (just in case, I'll set it for the snippet)
moment.locale('en');

// I have this string that's in the French locale
var str = "30 Avril 2015";

// Parsing it fails
var m = moment(str, "DD MMMM YYYY");
snippet.log(m.format("YYYY-MM-DD")); // "Invalid Date"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I posted it as it might be useful to someone anyway? I think I get what you want, you want some sort of "scope" where you can work on french dates for instance, without messing with the global locale.

Comment: @adeneo: Agreed. And yes, that's what I want. I'll post it separately.

Comment: You'd think there was a way to do that, but I can't remember ever seeing something like that? The documentation is rather extensive and I haven't read all of it, but I can't spot anything that would work like that, and you've probably looked as well. Could one perhaps extend moment to have a `set()` method on an instance or something like that ?

Comment: @adeneo: FYI, I've [posted the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435306/how-can-i-build-a-moment-function-that-works-in-a-non-global-locale).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version `2.0.0`, a locale key can be passed as the third parameter to `moment()` and `moment.utc()`

```js
// Assume the default locale is 'en' (just in case, I'll set it for the snippet)
moment.locale('en');

// I have this string that's in the French locale
var str = "30 Avril 2015";

// Parse it in 'fr'
var m = moment(str, "DD MMMM YYYY", "fr");

// Check result:
snippet.log(m.format("YYYY-MM-DD -- MMMM"));

// Check global locale
var locale = moment()._locale._abbr;
snippet.log('Locale : ' + locale);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer to the question I *actually asked*. Sadly, it's not quite the question I *meant* to ask. :-) (Which is pretty embarrassing; I've seen others do it so many times, you'd think I'd know better.) I'll also post the question I *meant* to ask, but this is the correct answer to this question. Thanks again.

Comment: It's the question *I* was wanting to ask, so useful to find it here! Thanks :)