# How can I build a 'moment' function that works in a non-global locale?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

With MomentJS, if necessary I can set a locale on a specific moment instance (rather than globally) using `.locale` (or `.lang` in older versions). How can I create a function equivalent to `moment` (all 42 signatures of it) that always works in a specific locale that's different from the global?

I have a submodule within a web project that has to work with a custom locale. We don't want this locale used outside this particular submodule, but we want it used consistently *within* that submodule. So I basically want a `moduleMoment` (or whatever) that I can call just like `moment`, but which works in the custom locale. Is there any built-in way to do that?

**Note**: I'm **not** talking about changing the locale of an **existing** instance, I'm talking about calling the `moment` function (in all its various different signatures) using a locale *other* than its global locale. So this won't work:

```
var m = moment(args).locale(localeId);
```

...because the args will be processed in the global locale, and then the locale gets changed on the instance after the fact, which is too late.

Comment: I don't think the question makes much sense: you are asking to change a property on an instance without having an instance to change it on. Of course that won't work (though I get what you want it for). Moment could expose a method `moment` on instances which does the same as the constructor itself, then you could do `moment().locale("fr").moment(…)`, but it doesn't as of now.

Comment: @IngoBürk: The question must make sense, you see to have understood it. :-) That's what I want: A means of processing the arguments in a non-global locale, and the question is basically: Does MomentJS have a way of doing that, now, that I've managed to miss in the docs. I don't think it does, but I could have missed it. Rather hoping I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can find to do it is to have a function that temporarily sets the locale, calls `moment`, then sets the locale back to the previous one, like this:

```
function moduleMoment() {
    var prevLocaleId, m;

    prevLocaleId = moment.locale();
    try {
        moment.locale(customLocaleId);
        m = moment.apply(this, arguments);
        return m;
    } finally {
        moment.locale(prevLocaleId);
    }
}
```

Or one could add it to `moment`, like this:

```
moment.localized = function(locale) {
    var prevLocaleId, m, args;

    prevLocaleId = moment.locale();
    try {
        moment.locale(locale);
        m = moment.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        return m;
    } finally {
        moment.locale(prevLocaleId);
    }
};
```

Comment: Not true-- you can change it per instance. (See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) Requires 1.7.0+

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Yes, but read the question again: I want to **call `moment`** using that locale. I can't change the instance locale without having an instance first!

Comment: Well, take a look at my answer and see if that works. I'm assuming in my answer that you have a locale in mind, but it's not too hard to add a parameter for that (I'll edit to reflect this).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortuntately it doesn't seem like Moment supports this functionality. There is a new feature request in the GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2291

<s>You could write a function that forwards its arguments to the `moment` constructor and then applies the language you want.</s>

Here's an example:

```
function localizedMoment() {
    return moment.apply(null, arguments).locale("fr");
}
```

If you need to allow a parameter, just use `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
function localizedMoment(locale) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(locale, 1);
    return moment.apply(null, args).locale(locale);
}
```

Comment: That's too late -- by then, the processing of the arguments has been done **before** the locale was applied. `localizedMoment("30 Avril 2015", "DD MMMM YYYY")` would fail, for instance. Now, for that **specific** case, we could use the locale argument (`moment("30 Avril 2015", "DD MMMM YYYY", "fr")`), but I'm talking about the *general* case.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Looks like there is a new feature request in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2291 If this were implemented, you could do `var m = moment().locale("locale"); m.set.apply(m, arguments);` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for that link, though it's just a special case of the general requirement. And thanks also for the attempt to answer the question, sorry the question wasn't as clear as it could have been initially.

Comment: True enough, though I can't see why `set` couldn't be adapted to just take all the same arguments as the constructor (or perhaps a different function, maybe `parse`).

Comment: I like your `set` idea -- in fact, that was the first place I looked.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance of removing the downvote? My answer is now correct in stating that it's not currently possible.

Comment: You're assuming I'm one of the people who downvoted; assumptions about voting are always  dangerous. :-) It *is* possible, it's just not supported directly in the API (as far as we can tell).