# How to set locale locally for moment.js

Tags: momentjs

The below code gives invalid date

```js
moment.locale('en'); 
var localLocale = moment('enero 22, 2017', 'MMMM DD, YYYY');

localLocale.locale('es');
alert(localLocale.format('L'));'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a date string in a specific locale (not timezone!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434952/parse-a-date-string-in-a-specific-locale-not-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import that particular locale js from Moment.js repo.

I've imported this in below code and this code works perfectly:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/locale/es.js

```
//! moment.js locale configuration
//! locale : Spanish [es]
//! author : Julio Napurí : https://github.com/julionc

;(function (global, factory) {
   typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined'
       && typeof require === 'function' ? factory(require('../moment')) :
   typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['../moment'], factory) :
   factory(global.moment)
}(this, (function (moment) { 'use strict';


var monthsShortDot = 'ene._feb._mar._abr._may._jun._jul._ago._sep._oct._nov._dic.'.split('_');
var monthsShort = 'ene_feb_mar_abr_may_jun_jul_ago_sep_oct_nov_dic'.split('_');

var monthsParse = [/^ene/i, /^feb/i, /^mar/i, /^abr/i, /^may/i, /^jun/i, /^jul/i, /^ago/i, /^sep/i, /^oct/i, /^nov/i, /^dic/i];
var monthsRegex = /^(enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre|ene\.?|feb\.?|mar\.?|abr\.?|may\.?|jun\.?|jul\.?|ago\.?|sep\.?|oct\.?|nov\.?|dic\.?)/i;

var es = moment.defineLocale('es', {
    months : 'enero_febrero_marzo_abril_mayo_junio_julio_agosto_septiembre_octubre_noviembre_diciembre'.split('_'),
    monthsShort : function (m, format) {
        if (!m) {
            return monthsShortDot;
        } else if (/-MMM-/.test(format)) {
            return monthsShort[m.month()];
        } else {
            return monthsShortDot[m.month()];
        }
    },
    monthsRegex : monthsRegex,
    monthsShortRegex : monthsRegex,
    monthsStrictRegex : /^(enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre)/i,
    monthsShortStrictRegex : /^(ene\.?|feb\.?|mar\.?|abr\.?|may\.?|jun\.?|jul\.?|ago\.?|sep\.?|oct\.?|nov\.?|dic\.?)/i,
    monthsParse : monthsParse,
    longMonthsParse : monthsParse,
    shortMonthsParse : monthsParse,
    weekdays : 'domingo_lunes_martes_miércoles_jueves_viernes_sábado'.split('_'),
    weekdaysShort : 'dom._lun._mar._mié._jue._vie._sáb.'.split('_'),
    weekdaysMin : 'do_lu_ma_mi_ju_vi_sá'.split('_'),
    weekdaysParseExact : true,
    longDateFormat : {
        LT : 'H:mm',
        LTS : 'H:mm:ss',
        L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        LL : 'D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY',
        LLL : 'D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY H:mm',
        LLLL : 'dddd, D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY H:mm'
    },
    calendar : {
        sameDay : function () {
            return '[hoy a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
        },
        nextDay : function () {
            return '[mañana a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
        },
        nextWeek : function () {
            return 'dddd [a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
        },
        lastDay : function () {
            return '[ayer a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
        },
        lastWeek : function () {
            return '[el] dddd [pasado a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
        },
        sameElse : 'L'
    },
    relativeTime : {
        future : 'en %s',
        past : 'hace %s',
        s : 'unos segundos',
        m : 'un minuto',
        mm : '%d minutos',
        h : 'una hora',
        hh : '%d horas',
        d : 'un día',
        dd : '%d días',
        M : 'un mes',
        MM : '%d meses',
        y : 'un año',
        yy : '%d años'
    },
    dayOfMonthOrdinalParse : /\d{1,2}º/,
    ordinal : '%dº',
    week : {
        dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
        doy : 4  // The week that contains Jan 4th is the first week of the year.
    }
});

return es;

})));
```

Your Code:

```
moment.updateLocale('es'); 
var localLocale = moment('enero 22, 2017', 'MMMM DD, YYYY');
alert(localLocale.format('L'));
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6df2xf80/